Hotreload with ts-node-dev
I want to use ts-node-dev for hotreloadign my app, but it does not work currently. I can't figure out what's wrong.
My package.json:
    "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js"
    },

My tsconfig.json:
    {
     "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es6",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "outDir": "./dist",
     "strict": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
     "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types",
      "./node_modules/@types/"
     ]
    },
     "include": [
     "src/**/*.ts"
     "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
     ]
    }

My console output after npm run dev:
[INFO] 00:24:22 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.2, typescript ver. 
5.5.3)
connected successfully to the mongodb
Server started successfully
Server running at http://localhost:3000

I expected a hotreload + information about it in the terminal. But my changes in index.ts do not trigger anything.
Thanks in advance.

The Problem is WSL2. When i run the command inside the windows terminal, it works as exspected. I stil prefer the wsl if someone has a solution.
